# wordpress frontend login and wp-admin not working right

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wp-admin

i did prevent all user are not admin from wp-admin with this code

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit();
}
}
```

and i created frontend login form with `wp_signon();` the problem is when i submit form in admin account it's successfully logged in but when trying access wp-admin it always return to home page url
so what's wrong and how can i fix this problem
my form

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['logingo']) && $_POST['logingo']=='logingo'){
    global $user;
    $creds = array();
    $username = (isset($_POST['login_name'])) ? $_POST['login_name'] : '';
    $password = (isset($_POST['login_password'])) ? $_POST['login_password'] : '';
    $creds['user_login'] = $username;
    $creds['user_password'] =  $password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $userid = wp_signon($creds,false);
    if(is_wp_error($user)){
        $proccess = '<div class="error_msg">'.$user->get_error_message().'</div>';
        $_SESSION['logged_errors'] = $proccess;
    }
    if(!is_wp_error($userid)){
        $_SESSION['logged_success'] = 'success message';
        wp_redirect(get_author_posts_url($userid->ID));
        exit();
    }
       }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label class="login_name">
                <input type="text" value="" name="login_name" required />
            </label>
            <label class="user_password">
                <input type="password" name="login_password" required />
            </label>
               <button type="submit" name="logingo" value="logingo">go</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: in your if condition you need to put " ! is_admin() " instead of  is_admin(). Try and check is it working or not?

Comment: but that make my frontend not working cause it's not is_admin

Answer (score 0):

This may be a result of the following issues:

1. Code Snippet that redirects to homepage in wp-login.php: post the code of your login page in the question.
2. Cookie problem: Clear your browser cookies and cache, restart your browser and try login
3. Plugin: Have you activated a login plugin? Or maybe its another plugin that is causing issues. Deactivate all plugins and see if succesful.
4. Theme issue: maybe there is something wrong with your theme. Change to default theme and install your desired theme afresh. Hook your Access-Limit code to functions.php

I recommend you use a [pre-built plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/) to limit access to WordPress dashboard for non-admin users, if not create your own plugin. Changing code in functions.php is not advisable see [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-functions-php/)

Comment: no i don't use any plugin and i clear my cookies more times in first login work just fine but in second login not working right

Answer (score 0):

This quick snippet will force WordPress to redirect to the URL that you specify in wp_redirect() when a user fails to login. We also append a $_GET variable, login, and set it equal to failed, which we can use in our theme to display special content only when the user has failed to login.

```
 add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'pippin_login_fail' );  // hook failed login
 function pippin_login_fail( $username ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
      wp_redirect(home_url() . '/?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
      exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: when logout from frontend and wp-admin is opened in another tab i logged in again but wp-admin not opening